# usage of \only with counter, pdfcomment and beamer class

Tags: beamer, counters, pdfcomment

I cannot manage to get the following command to work. I have a `beamer` presentation with several slides on a frame. Then I want to use the `pdfcomment` package to show some comments on the slides. Usually this works fine, but on frames with multiple steps, it's annoying, because the comments appear on each slide (and they are visible on each slide, even if the respective text has not appeared yet!). So my solution is the following:

I calculate the slide number on the frame and the use the `\only` command to show the comment only of the last slide of the frame. In my example, this is the fifth slide on the frame. The command works like this:

```
\only<5>{\pdfcomment[style=note,author=name]{comment...}}
```

However, as it is quite annoying to find the last slide on the frame by hand, I tried to define a command, which reads:

```
\newcommand{\pdfnote}[2]{%
\setcounter{slidenum}{\insertpagenumber}
\addtocounter{slidenum}{1}
\addtocounter{slidenum}{-\insertframestartpage}
\only<\value{slidenum}>{\pdfcomment[style=note,author=#1]{#2}}%
}
```

Basically it uses the counter `slidenum`, which contains the last slide on the frame, e.g. 2. The routine works, except that the `pdfcomment` is visible on all slides! It's kind of weird, because when I simply replace `\value{slidenum}` with 2, it works. And I just added the line `\arabic{slidenum}` just before the `\only` command so check if the counter is correct. Furthermore I replaced the `\pdfcomment` by a simple text. That's working as well.

By the way: `\only` does work, `\onslide` does not work at all for `pdfcomment`. I really don't understand. Do you have any ideas? Below you find a complete example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[draft,author=admin]{pdfcomment}

\definestyle{note}{icon=Comment,color=white,open=true}
\definestyle{warning}{icon=Comment,color=red,open=true}

\newcounter{slidenum}

\newcommand{\pdfnote}[2]{%
\setcounter{slidenum}{\insertpagenumber}
\addtocounter{slidenum}{1}
\addtocounter{slidenum}{-\insertframestartpage}
%\arabic{slidenum}
\only<\value{slidenum}>{\pdfcomment[style=note,author=#1]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

test\\ \pause
next line
\pdfnote{me}{my comment}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test exactly the reason why it doesn't work but it is apparent that the calculations fall short and it is being shown on every slide, although the number shown is correct.

However, you can use the internal counter of `beamer` which is the `beamerpauses` counter. As the name implies it is incremented whenever there is an overlay specification is given.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[draft,author=admin]{pdfcomment}
\definestyle{note}{icon=Comment,color=white,open=true}
\definestyle{warning}{icon=Comment,color=red,open=true}
\newcommand{\pdfnote}[2]{%
\onslide*<\value{beamerpauses}>{\pdfcomment[style=note,author=#1]{#2}}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
test\\ \pause
next line
\pdfnote{me}{comment 1}
\\ \pause
adsf
\pdfnote{me}{comment 2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have changed `\only` to `\onslide*` to show yet another possibility which is effectively the same thing as stated in the manual.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's kind of working, but only if I actually use \pause for overlays. In practive I am usually using <number> (e.g. \item<3->) and so on. beamerpauses does not notice those overlays and thus the counter stays 1 all the time and the comment appears alsways on the first slide, not on the last, as intended.

Comment: I don't have a general solution yet for this.

Answer (score 0):

In the following, I define a `\thelastslideofframe` command that, **after the second `pdflatex` run**, expands to the number of slides in the current frame. It can be fed into `\only<>`and so on  and works with `\pause` as well as with explicit overlay specifications.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[draft,author=admin]{pdfcomment}

\definestyle{note}{icon=Comment,color=white,open=true}
\definestyle{warning}{icon=Comment,color=red,open=true}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\thelastslideofframe{%
  \the\numexpr0\beamer@endpageofframe-0\beamer@startpageofframe+1%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\pdfnote}[2]{%
  \only<\thelastslideofframe>{\pdfcomment[style=note,author=#1]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \onslide<3>{This is slide 3, the last slide of this frame!\par}
  test\\ \pause
  next line
  \pdfnote{me}{My comment, on last slide only (after second compilation)}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have found a small glitch, though: If one _reduces_ the number of slides, `\thelastslideofframe` still contains the old value on the next `pdflatex` run. In this run, we insert content (the PDF comment) with `\only<\thelastslideofframe>`, so that after this run the number of slides **is again** the original value of `\thelastslideofframe`. Solution/Workaround: Delete the `.nav` auxiliary file.