# Use of forloop-counter inside beamer \only

Tags: beamer, counters, loops

I'm using LaTeX beamer and the `forloop`-package to create a for loop, and I want to use the counter inside an `\only-command`. Here is a MWE (or more like non-working example):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{forloop}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    \newcounter{slideno}
    \forloop{slideno}{1}{\value{slideno} < 20}{
      \only<\value{slideno}>{\arabic{slideno}}%
    }
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@slideno already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

Now, the post over here[0] tells me that using counters like this in `\only` should be possible, and in fact, if I comment out the for-loop (and add a `\setcounter`), it works like a charm.

Does the for-loop some magic to the counter? Can I somehow circumvent this?

Thanks a lot,

Lukas

[0] [usage of \only with counter, pdfcomment and beamer class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46242/usage-of-only-with-counter-pdfcomment-and-beamer-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `frame` itself does replicate the content somehow with each slide, a `\newcounter` command inside a `frame` with more than slide is of course leading to a multiple definition of `slideno`, which is wrong.

Put the `\newcounter{slideno}` definition into the preamble (which is always a good idea for counters.)

There's also missing `%` in the `\forloop`

```
   \forloop{slideno}{1}{\value{slideno} < 20}{
      \only<\value{slideno}>{\arabic{slideno}}%
    }
```

will lead to numbers moving to the right, 
whereas

```
   \forloop{slideno}{1}{\value{slideno} < 20}{%
      \only<\value{slideno}>{\arabic{slideno}}%
    }
```

will provide 'stationary' numbers.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{slideno}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    \forloop{slideno}{1}{\value{slideno} < 20}{%
      \only<\value{slideno}>{\arabic{slideno}}%
    }
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```